# Flutter: How to access values of individual child widgets from a list created at runtime

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider

I'm receiving a list of JSON objects at runtime and dynamically creating a list of sliderWidgets (See image) based on these JSON Objects. I need to access the sliderValues of these sliderWidgets in the parent widget (being the main screen) when I press the FloatingActionButton, as this will save the sliderValues into a CSV File. How the hell am I supposed to access the sliderValues without doing something really ugly here? Since the list is dynamically created at runtime and might have a large amount of objects inside of it, I’m not sure how I would do this.

[image]

I tried accessing the objects with keys, to no avail. I'm also not sure this would be best practice.

Below is the code with unimportant parts left out

```
class MorningSurveyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MorningSurveyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MorningSurveyScreen> createState() => _MorningSurveyScreenState();
}

class _MorningSurveyScreenState extends State<MorningSurveyScreen> {

  late List<Widget> _userVariablesWidgets; // This is the variable where I save my sliderWidget list

  didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    _userVariablesWidgets = UserVariablesHelper.getUserVariablesWidgets(Provider.of<UserVariablesModel>(context, listen: true).userVariables); 
// This is where I start listening for my list of sliderWidgets
  }
  
  Future<void> _addEntry() async {
    bool addEntry = await DialogHelper.showAddEntryDialog(context);
    if (addEntry) {
      await CsvDataService.addRowToCsv({
        // THIS POINT IS WHERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE SLIDER VALUES
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //wrap in consumer
    return Consumer<UserVariablesModel>(
        builder: (context, userVariablesModel, child) => Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // OTHER WIDGETS,
                      ..._userVariablesWidgets // These are my sliderWidgets
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 16,
                  right: 16,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _addEntry,
                    tooltip: 'Add entry',
                    child: const Icon(Icons.check),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

For completeness these are my sliderWidgets, also condensed for readability

```
class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final SliderVariable sliderVariable;
  // This holds sliderWidget min, max values and question label.
  // However, it is unimportant for us right now

  SliderWidget({Key? key, required this.sliderVariable});

  @override
  State<SliderWidget> createState() => _SliderWidgetState();
}

class _SliderWidgetState extends State<SliderWidget> {
  late double currentSliderValue = widget.sliderVariable.min.toDouble();
// This is the value I need to access from my MorningSurveyScreen

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // OTHER WIDGETS,
        Slider(
          value: currentSliderValue,
          min: widget.sliderVariable.min.toDouble(),
          max: widget.sliderVariable.max.toDouble(),
          divisions: widget.sliderVariable.max - widget.sliderVariable.min,
          label: currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
          onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              currentSliderValue = value;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made an example of how it should be implemented using `Provider` package which you already use so you can adjust it to your needs.
This is the `UserVariablesModel` provider sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserVariablesModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<SliderVariable> _userVariables = [
    SliderVariable(min: 0, max: 10, question: 'How would you rate your sleep?'),
    SliderVariable(
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        question: 'How many times did you wake up in the night?'),
  ];

  List<SliderVariable> get userVariables => List.unmodifiable(_userVariables);

  updateVariable(SliderVariable sliderVariable, double value) {
    final index = userVariables.indexOf(sliderVariable);
    if (index != -1) {
      _userVariables[index] = sliderVariable.copyWith(value: value);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}

class SliderVariable {
  double min;
  double max;
  double value;
  String question;

  SliderVariable({
    required this.min,
    required this.max,
    double? value,
    required this.question,
  }) : value = value ?? min;

  SliderVariable copyWith({
    double? min,
    double? max,
    double? value,
    String? question,
  }) {
    return SliderVariable(
      min: min ?? this.min,
      max: max ?? this.max,
      value: value ?? this.value,
      question: question ?? this.question,
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the example of how to use it to reflect the changes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test/business/user_variables_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => UserVariablesModel(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: MorningSurveyScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MorningSurveyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MorningSurveyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<void> _addEntry(List<SliderVariable> sliderVariables) async {
    print("slider values:");
    for (var userVariable in sliderVariables) {
      print(userVariable.value);
    }

    // bool addEntry = await DialogHelper.showAddEntryDialog(context);
    // if (addEntry) {
    //   await CsvDataService.addRowToCsv({
    //     // THIS POINT IS WHERE I NEED TO ACCESS THE SLIDER VALUES
    //   });
    // }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //wrap in consumer
    return Consumer<UserVariablesModel>(
      builder: (context, userVariablesModel, child) => Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                // OTHER WIDGETS,
                for (var sliderVariable in userVariablesModel.userVariables)
                  SliderWidget(sliderVariable: sliderVariable)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 16,
            right: 16,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => _addEntry(userVariablesModel.userVariables),
              tooltip: 'Add entry',
              child: const Icon(Icons.check),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final SliderVariable sliderVariable;

  const SliderWidget({Key? key, required this.sliderVariable})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentSliderValue = sliderVariable.value.toDouble();
    return Column(
      children: [
        // OTHER WIDGETS,
        Slider(
          value: currentSliderValue,
          min: sliderVariable.min.toDouble(),
          max: sliderVariable.max.toDouble(),
          divisions: (sliderVariable.max - sliderVariable.min).toInt(),
          label: currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
          onChanged: (double value) {
            Provider.of<UserVariablesModel>(context, listen: false)
                .updateVariable(sliderVariable, value);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid saving the value of the slider in SliderVariable, as that should only contain the values I referred to before (Like min, max and label) which correspond to the values found in the JSON object... But I guess maybe this is the easiest way in the end. I could also create a class exclusively for the sliderValues but I doubt that would make my code much cleaner.

Comment: I feel that the value property fits in the SliderVariable model because the value determines that model's slider (widget) value. Of course you could create a class for the sliderValues but you would need to refer (connect it) to the SliderValue model somehow, so I think that the initial solution (to include it in the model) is the easiest and better solution for this case.

Comment: That makes sense actually, thanks!